# Mysql Select records time between '23:57:58' AND '00:07:58'

Tags: mysql

for the current time I add 5 minutes

```
$maxTime = date('H:i:s', strtotime('+5 minutes', strtotime($formatedAusDateTime)));
$minTime = date('H:i:s', strtotime('-5 minutes', strtotime($formatedAusDateTime)));
```

for time range I am getting '23:57:58' AND '00:07:58' with this time range It is not selected "00:02:45". What is the error with this approach, How can I select "00:02:45" row with give time range.

Query Is this,

```
SELECT * FROM v2 WHERE v2.cli = '835' AND (v2.call_time>= '23:57:58' AND v2.call_time<= '00:07:58');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to differentiate between `$maxTime > $minTime` and `$maxTime < $minTime`

For the case of `$maxTime > $minTime` it is `AND`:

```
AND (v2.call_time>= '22:57:58' AND v2.call_time<= '23:07:58');
```

For the case of `$maxTime < $minTime` it is `OR`:

```
AND (v2.call_time>='23:57:58' OR v2.call_time<= '00:07:58');
```

Depending on the API you use to communicate with MySQL you could write that in one query using prepared statements and named parameters.

Something like, but that as I said depends on the API. In this case, it is how it could look like in with php PDO:

```
AND (
      (
         (:minTime<:maxTime) AND (v2.call_time>=:minTime AND v2.call_time<=:maxTime)
      )
      OR
      (
         (:minTime>:maxTime) AND (v2.call_time>=:minTime OR v2.call_time<=:maxTime)
      )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Condition `'00:02:45' (v2.call_time) > '23:57:58'` is false.

If you need to compare records around midnight, compare full datetime, not just time.

Eg.

```
SELECT * FROM v2 WHERE v2.cli = '835' AND (v2.call_time>= '2020-06-06 23:57:58' AND v2.call_time<= '2020-06-07 00:07:58');
```

Of course, you need to store datetime instead of time.